# What are the best practices for hadoop benchmarking?

Tags: apache, hadoop, benchmarking, bigdata

I am using TestDFSIO to benchmark hadoop I/O performance.
The test rig I am using is a small virtual cluster of 3 data nodes and one name node.
Each vm would have 6-8 GB RAM and 100-250 GB HDD.

I want to know about two things:

1. What should be the values for number of files(nrFIles) and file size for each file (fileSize) parameters with respect to my set up such that we can relate the results of my small cluster to clusters of standard sizes like having 8-12 x 2-TB hard disks and 64 GBs of RAM and higher processing speeds. Is it even correct to do so.
2. In general what are the best practices for benchmarking hadoop? Like:
   what is the recommended cluster specification(specs of datanodes, namenodes), recommended test data size, what configurations/specs should the test bed have in order to have results which will conform to real life hadoop applications

Simply said I want to know about the correct hadoop test rig setup and correct test methods so that my results are relatable to production clusters.

It will be helpful to have references to proven work.

Another question is 
suppose i have -nrFiles 15 -fileSize 1GB
I found that number of map tasks will be equal to the number mentioned for nrFiles
But how are they distributed among the 3 data nodes? 15 number of map tasks is not clear to me. Is it like for 15 files each file will have one mapper working on it?

I have not found any document or description of how exactly testDFSIO works.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I hope I made my question more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare results for two clusters. the results may vary on number of mappers on a node, replication factor, network etc.
Cluster specification would depend on what are you trying to use it for.
If you provide -nrFiles 15 -fileSize 1000 there would be 15 files created of each 1GB. each mapper would work on a single file, so there would be 15 map tasks. for your 3 node cluster assuming you just have 1 mapper on a node there would be 5 waves to write the full data.
refer the below link for testDFSIO and other benchmarking tools: http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I was also beginning to think the same thing, That we cannot compare two clusters, the results belong to only my cluster and cannot define any other cluster.